# How will the gas fee be allocated in ethereum 2.0?

Tags: gas, eth-2.0, validators

Such as title, how will the gas fee be allocated to validator in ethereum 2.0? Will give it all to the block proposer?

I don't see an explanation for this in the official documents.

My idea is this:
gas fee now has two functions:

- as the reward to miners for the work they do;
- as a defense against denial-of-service attacks;

after eip 1559, gas fee comprise of base fee and tip fee, base fee will be burned.
while in ethereum 2.0, the network will not congested, so no user will pay tip fee.
so gas fee will only remain one function in ethereum 2.0: against denial-of-service attacks.
the incentive of validator will be new issued ETH.

is this opinion TRUE?

Answer (score 1):

After "The Merge" (when Ethereum moves to proof-of-stake), each proposer of a block on the Ethereum Beacon Chain (a.k.a. "eth2") chooses a "fee recipient" to receive the gas fees from the transactions in that block.

It is assumed that the block proposer will select their own address as the fee recipient. So, generally speaking, gas fees will go to proof-of-stake validators in much the same way that they go to proof-of-work miners now.

So, in answer to your question *"Will give it all to the block proposer?"*, my answer is "yes".

> while in ethereum 2.0, the network will not congested

This is a dubious assumption which I would not take as fact. I don't think it would be appropriate for me to engage with this statement in this forum.